# Variable params[:action] en modelo en RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy tratando de trabajar con la variable action en eun modelo en rails, pero me genera este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea??? de antemano, Gracias!!!

Adjunto del controller

```
class MensajesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_mensaje, only: [:show, :alcance, :edit, :update, :grupo, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :cuota_sms

  def create
    @mensaje = Mensaje.new(mensaje_params) do |mensaje|
    mensaje.user = current_user
    mensaje.parent_id = params[:parent_id]
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def alcance
    mensaje = {"mensajes_id_in_any"=>[params[:id].to_s]}
    @buscar = Contacto.search(mensaje)
    @enviado_por = 'xxx'
    @contactos = @buscar.result(distinct: true).order("numero")
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @mensaje.update(mensaje_params)
        format.html { redirect_to '/', notice: 'mensaje editado' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @contacto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def grupo
    respond_to do |format|
      if @mensaje.update(mensaje_params)
        format.html { redirect_to mensaje_path, notice: 'Alcance actualizado' }
      else
        format.html { render :show }
        format.json { render json: @contacto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @mensaje_id = params[:id]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  private
  def set_mensaje
    @mensaje = Mensaje.find(params[:id])
  end

  def mensaje_params
    params.require(:mensaje).permit(:texto, :cantidad_contactos, grupo_ids:[], mensaje_ids:[])
  end

end
```

Adjunto código completo del modelo

---

```````````````````````````````````````````
class Mensaje < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :grupos
  has_and_belongs_to_many :contactos

  after_update   :actualizar_mensaje

  self.per_page = 20

  belongs_to :user

  validates :texto,
  presence: { message: "en blanco" },
  length: { maximum: 160, :message => "muy largo" }

  counter_culture :user
end

private
  def actualizar_mensaje
   puts '``````````````````````````````````````````'
   puts '``````````````````````````````````````````'
   puts "accion: #{params[:action]}"
   puts '``````````````````````````````````````````'
   puts '``````````````````````````````````````````'
    contador = 0 
    vector = []
    gm = GruposMensaje.where(mensaje_id: self.id)
    gm.each do |gml|
      grp = Grupo.find(gml.grupo_id)
      cg = ContactosGrupo.where(grupo_id: grp.id) 
      cg.each do |cgl|
        contacto = Contacto.find(cgl.contacto_id)
        vector[contador] = contacto.id
        contador += 1
      end
    end
    vector = vector.sort.uniq
    total = vector.length
    mensaje = Mensaje.find(self.id)
    mensaje.update_columns(cantidad_contactos: total)

    mensaje.contactos.delete_all
    vector.each do |id_contacto|
      ContactosMensaje.create( { "mensaje_id" => self.id, "contacto_id" => id_contacto })
    end
  end
```````````````````````````````````````````

Básicamente lo que quiero es que cuando llame a la acción **update** en el controlador se ejecute el ***after_update :actualizar_mensaje***, pero cuando invoque la acción **grupo**, no se ejecute after_update   :actualizar_mensaje.

Comment: Por favor, no pongas imagnes con texto. Para eso pone el codigo de error en formato de texto en la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el código del controlador relacionado así como una breve descripción de lo que deseas lograr? Tal como [respondió Alter Lagos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/100496/42433), no puedes accesar `params` desde el modelo, pero podrías enviar la información de `params`  al modelo utilizando variables. Si nos das más detalle de lo que deseas lograr será más sencillo ayudarte.

Comment: El _callback_ `after_update :actualizar_mensaje` se está ejecutando correctamente, pero te muestra el error debido a que tienes `params[:action]` dentro del método (insisto, no se tiene acceso a `params` en el modelo); pero no veo que utilices `params[:action]` en ningún lado más que en `puts` (¿a modo de _debug_?), por lo que lo único que debes hacer es eliminar las lineas `puts` y el error desaparecerá. ¿Por qué tienes `params[:action]` ahí?

Comment: si, lo puse a modo de debug, (reconozco que estoy empezando en esto del mundo RoR y todavia los procesos debug del lenguaje), tal y como lo comenté en el ultimo parrafo, lo que quiero es que el callback after_update se ejecute en la accion update, pero que NO se se jecute en la accion grupo.

Comment: @rrg1459 revisa la actualización de mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

La variable `params` no es accesible a nivel de modelo, solo desde el controlador o la vista.

**Actualización**

Hay varias formas de hacer lo que requieres. Una, que creo que es la más sencilla, es que simplemente saques el `after_update`, dejes tu método `actualizar_mensaje` como público y llames al método desde el controlador cuando lo requieras:

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @mensaje.update(mensaje_params)
         # Aquí es requerido, así que lo llamas
        @mensaje.actualizar_mensaje
        format.html { redirect_to '/', notice: 'mensaje editado' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @contacto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def grupo
    respond_to do |format|
      if @mensaje.update(mensaje_params)
         # Aquí no, entonces no haces nada
        format.html { redirect_to mensaje_path, notice: 'Alcance actualizado' }
      else
        format.html { render :show }
        format.json { render json: @contacto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Si no quieres agregar lógica en el controlador, podrías crear dos métodos `update1` y `update2` en el modelo y que ambos llamen a update, pero uno llame al método  `actualizar_mensaje` y el otro no.

Otra opción, que podría ser más adecuada, es crear en tu modelo un `attr_accessor` con un booleano que defina si el mensaje es de grupo o no. Algo como:

```
class Mensaje < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :es_grupo

  after_update :actualizar_mensaje, unless: :es_grupo?
```

Para esto, deberías mandar esa variable, ya sea agregándola desde tu controlador con algo como `@mensaje.update(mensaje_params.merge(grupo: true))` o, mejor aún, desde el formulario de la vista.

Punto aparte, creo que tu action `grupo` en el controlador no tiene sentido que exista si hace lo mismo que `update` a excepción de llamar al método `actualizar_mensaje`, lo cual, como te comento, puedes controlar perfectamente indicando desde la vista si requieres o no llamarlo.

Comment: Como puedo saber de que accion del controlador estoy llamando al modelo?

Comment: @rrg1459 según lo que muestra el log de tu pantallazo es desde mensajes_controller#update, línea 35

Comment: Si eso los se, el tema es que lo llamo desde dos acciones en el controlador, con una acción quiero que haga algo y con la otra acción quiero que haga otra cosa.

Comment: @rrg1459 podrías enviar un parámetro desde donde llames al método del modelo que determine lo que va a realizar.

Comment: Escribi el merge al parametro @mensaje.update(mensaje_params.merge(grupo: true))  y da este error: 
 ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError at /mensajes/6

unknown attribute 'grupo' for Mensaje.******* ****** ******* adicionalmente me parecio interesante la propuesta del formulario en la vista y estuve viendo en preguntas similares pero no se como integrarlo a la vista.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que puedo observar el error es por que en el controller no tienes una acción para esa ruta, estaría bien que subieras el código de tu controller.

Subo un ejemplo de un controller:

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_ticket, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  respond_to :html, :json

  # GET /tickets/1
  # GET /tickets/1.json
  def show

  end

private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_ticket
      @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def ticket_params
      params.require(:ticket).permit(:subtotal, :total, :pay_with, :change, :status)
    end
end
```

Como se puede observar antes de cada accion, show, edit, update y drestroy, setea el ticket `@ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])`, en este caso te enviara con la ruta http://localhost:3000/tickets/1 debera enviar las propiedas del ticket con id=1, siempre y cuando exista.

Comment: El error (imagen) muestra que el problema está en el modelo (tal como lo describe Alter Lagos en [su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/100496/42433)); de hecho la ruta y controlador parecen estar en orden, lo puedes ver en el pequeño `trace` el cual muestra se ejecutó la acción `update`, la cual llama al modelo y ahí es donde se genera el error.

Comment: Así es efectivamente, debería de agregar el código del controller y el model para poder ayudarlo, por que seguido de eso envía error en controller en la linea 35 y linea 36 según la imagen. ¿Que querrá hacer con `actualizar_mensaje`?

Comment: Realmente el controller como tal no tiene error (o por lo menos no que se muestre en la imagen); el trace muestra esas líneas (35 y 36) indicando la secuencia de ejecución que siguió antes de encontrarse con el error; es decir, ejecutó la acción update en la línea 35, esa acción ejecutó un bloque en la línea 36, ese bloque ejecutó el método actualizar_mensaje, dentro del cual se generó un error, específicamente en la línea 23. Eso sí, para poder brindar mayor ayuda al OP, es necesario ver su controlador completo. :)